# Pseudo 3D Track editor

Tags: 2d

Does anyone know of a pseudo 3D track editor ? I now need one to design my stages, as manually trying to create segments, and position static and movable objects would be too time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

There is Layout https://github.com/djyt/layout/wiki a track editor that works with Outrun.

The biggest issue with a 'generic' track editor would be if the format matches the goal of your game. The above track editor can create Outrun style levels with all the features of the Outrun engine (for example two parallel tracks and scenary works with patterns). 
IIRC it can export a XML like format, so it may suit your needs, and proxy some of the elements with your own features.

I made my own track editor inspired by this one, to support the features of my own game like this:[image: my own track-editor]

Comment: The problem with Layout is that it is too specific to Outrun to be much use.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I rolled my own. I wouldn't know of a generic format (like Tiled for tilemaps) to have a generic track layout tool.

Comment: Which is fair enough - I'm going towards parsing a CSV file.  Dont really have the time to modify someone elses code.